# Where is the AWS deletion-dependency graph documented?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dependencies, aws-nuke

Is the AWS deletion-dependency graph documented somewhere? In other words, documentation that says that if you want to delete resource A, you must first delete resource B, which A somehow depends on?

This [unimplemented feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1721) and [this page](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-dependency-error-delete-vpc) emphasize the difficulty. An easy example is that you cannot delete a VPC until you delete instances in it, but there are dozens of these dependencies for VPCs, and each of these has a specific kind of named relationship to the VPC.

**And that is just for the VPC resource type**, which is one of hundreds of types of resources in AWS.

I want to clean up (delete) resources. AWSNuke does that, but is not aware of deletion-dependencies. It handles them by trying to delete them all in multiple passes -- eventually any given dependency for a given resource is deleted.

And more generally, it seems that this should be documented somewhere.

Comment: No, I haven't seen such a graph documented anywhere.

Comment: There is no such documentation. If there were, then AWSNuke could have been designed using that documentation, and it wouldn't need to make multiple passes.